# parsing a table within HTML using python

Tags: python, html, parsing

I've been trying to parse information from a web page. Basically, I want to pull some information from the table within the HTML so I can trend it. The part I am stuck on is parsing the HTML within the table.

The web page is http://weather.unbc.ca/wx/data-table.html

I've tried to use:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


contenturl = "http://weather.unbc.ca/wx/data-table.html"


soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(contenturl).read())

table = soup.find('tr', attrs={'class': 'content'})

rows = table.findAll('tr')
for tr in rows:
cols = tr.findAll('td')
if 'cell_c' in cols[0]['class']:
    # currency row
        Date_time, Record, Tair, Tdew, RH, pstn, pmsl, wspd_avg, wspd_vec,      wdir, wstd, wgust, precip, solarq, solarq_un, kdown, kdown_dif, Sun, Ldown = [c.text for c in cols]
        print Date_time, Record, Tair, Tdew, RH, pstn, pmsl, wspd_avg, wspd_vec, wdir, wstd, wgust, precip, solarq, solarq_un, kdown, kdown_dif, Sun, Ldown
```

I seem to get the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\data.py", line 14, in 
    rows = table.findAll('tr')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Pardon my ignorance on beautiful soup. I am totally open to other approaches. 
My goal is to put the last line in the table into variables so I can trend.

Answer (score 0):

**NoneType** basically means **soup.find** returned None.

I'm no expert in **BeautifulSoup** or **urllib** but my wild guess is that it couldn't find any **tr** with class **content**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I guess I need more help with beautifulsoup. I can print the 'soup' and it shows a lot of tr. I'll try and do some more research on how to better take this and put it into a table - I must be doing something wrong there.

Comment: Try to check the HTML of the page you are trying to pull data from. maybe u missed something there.